# How to filter on more than one record mongodb embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql

This is my model:

```
order:{
        _id: 88565,
        activity: 
        [
           {_id: 57235, content: "foo"},
           {_id: 57236, content: "bar"}
        ]
}
```

This is my query:

```
db.order.find({
        "$and": [
            {
                "activity.content "bar"
            },
            {
                "activity._id": 57235
            }
        ]
    });
```

This query will select the order with id 88565 even if the conditions are satisfied together by 2 different embedded activities.

I would expect that this query returned nothing.
I know that I can use elemMatch to filter embedded documents with more precision but this behaviour seems very confusing.

Is there a way to obtain a proper filtering where an AND clause has a single embedded document scope?

Comment: This behavior makes perfect sense to me since each element of the `$and` is a separate truth value evaluated with no ties to the other one. The `$and` only comes into place when making sure that both separate evaluations return true, independently of eachother, then use those truth values to evaluate whether the entire document should be returned by the query.

Comment: The basic answer is that you can't do that with `$and` because it operates at the document level, which is why `$elemMatch` is necessary.